Vertical integration and transfer price
A firm has an upstream engine division and a downstream car division. The total cost of engine production is $T C_U=Q^2 / 2$. The total cost of car assembly is $T C_D=Q^2 / 2$. The demand for the company's cars is $P_D=3$. There is a competitive outside market in which the price of an engine is $P_O=2$. How many cars does the company produce? What is the quantity of engines that the company buys or sells on the outside market?
(a) The transfer price for engines should equal the market price of 2 . The profits of the downstream division are $\pi_D=3 Q-Q^2 / 2-2 Q=Q-Q^2 / 2$. The optimization condition is $1-Q=0$, which gives $Q=1$ as the number of cars produced.
(b) The transfer price for engines should equal the market price of 2 . The profits of the upstream division are $\pi_U=2 Q-Q^2 / 2$. The optimization condition is $2-Q=0$, which gives $Q=2$ as the number of engines produced. The downstream division buys 1 engine from the upstream division, and the upstream division sells 1 engine on the outside market.
My question: I feel hard to interpret the concept the transfer price here. I think the transfer price is just the selling price of upstream firm and cost of downstream firm?
Another question is in the solution of part (b), we get the $Q=2$. But the solution said only 1 engine is sold and bought. I don't understand.

For your question about (b): $1+1=2$
